# Disable Wine debugger and kill process instead

Tags: wine

I am running a Windows program through Wine (i.e., `wine example.exe`). The program (or, more likely, Wine) has the funny behavior that instead of cleanly exiting when I close the application, it throws a read access exception; my terminal reads:

```
wine: Unhandled page fault on read access to 0x00000018 at address 0x7f7969ea (thread 0009), starting debugger...
```

As a result, the program doesn't exit cleanly and I have to Control-C in the terminal or `kill -9` it to close the program.

**Question:** Is there a way to have the wine process exit whenever there is an unhandled page fault, instead of starting the debugger as the terminal output suggests? (An aside: the debugger doesn't actually start; there is a subsequent message complaining about errors starting the wine debugger.)

Comment: Related bug: https://bugs.winehq.org/show_bug.cgi?id=49556

Answer (score 2):

The canonical way to do this is to create the HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Wine\winedbg key and set the DWORD value ShowCrashDialog to 0.

Comment: Things might have changed since you posted this, but `winetricks nocrashdialog` is another options.  Details here -> https://code.google.com/archive/p/malware-crawler/wikis/WineConfig.wiki  But I'm upvoting this answer as it pointed me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

This python script implements the workaround suggested by @chzzh in the comments. Basically, it reads the stderr of the wine process and forcibly kills it when it finds a specified string, e.g., when it finds the string `starting debugger...` in stderr.

Here is how to use it: save the script below as `watcher.py` (any name works). Then

`python3 ./watcher.py 'starting debugger...' wine <arguments and exe path for wine>`

I've tested this and it works well for me.

Here is the script:

```
#!/bin/python3
import sys
import io
import select
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, DEVNULL, STDOUT
from sys import argv

def kill_when_found(process, needle, size = io.DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE):
    if isinstance(needle, str):
        needle = needle.encode()
    assert isinstance(needle, bytes)

    stream = process.stderr
    assert stream is not None

    poll = select.poll()
    poll.register(stream, select.POLLIN)

    output_buffer = b''
    while process.poll() is None:
        result = poll.poll(100)
        if not result:
            continue

        output = stream.read1(size)
        sys.stdout.buffer.write(output)
        output_buffer += output
        if needle in output_buffer:
            process.kill()
            return process.poll()

        if len(output_buffer) >= len(needle):
            output_buffer = output_buffer[-len(needle):]

    return process.poll()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    if len(argv) <= 3:
        print("""
Usage: Pass in at least 2 arguments, the first argument is the search
string;
the remaining arguments form the command to be executed (and watched over).
""")
        sys.exit(0)
    else:
        process = Popen(argv[2:], stderr = PIPE)
        retcode = kill_when_found(process, argv[1])
        sys.exit(retcode)
```